# modifying data.table by reference with 'lapply' and 'by' creates duplicate rows for grouping columns

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

This may have been asked before and I have looked through [Reference semantics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) but I can't seem to find the answer. SO also suggested revising my title, so I will be fine if someone posts a link to the answer!

I have a MWE below. I am trying to group by column `val` by the day of each month. From my understanding, in SCENARIO 1 below in the code, since I am not assigning the values of `lapply` to any new column through `:=`, the `data.table` is printed.

However, in SCENARIO 2, when I assign new column variables by reference using `:=` the new columns are created (with the correct values) but the value is repeated for every hour of the day, when I want just the daily values.

SCENARIO 3 also gives the desired result, but requires the creation of a new `data.table`.

I also wouldn't think of `set` because `value` iterates by row, and I need to group certain columns.

Thanks for any help,

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(123)

# create data.table to group by
dt <- data.table(year = rep(2018, times = 24 * 31),
                 month = rep(1, times = 24 * 31),
                 day = rep(1:31, each = 24),
                 hour = rep(0:23, times = 31)) %>% 
  .[, val := sample(100, size = nrow(dt), replace = TRUE)]


# SCENARIO 1
# creates desired dataframe but only prints it, doesn't modify dt by reference (because it is missing `:=`)
dt[, lapply(.SD,
            sum),
   .SDcols = "val",
   by = .(year,
          month,
          day)]


# Scenario 2
# creates desired val column, but creates duplicate val values for all rows of original grouping by data.table
dt[, val := lapply(.SD,
                   sum),
   .SDcols = "val",
   by = .(year,
          month,
          day)]


# SCENARIO 3
# this also works, but requires creating a new data.table
new_dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD,
                      sum),
             .SDcols = "val",
             by = .(year,
                    month,
                    day)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in the creation of the new data.table object, you can do it with the same name to rewrite.

```
     dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD,
                      sum),
             .SDcols = "val",
             by = .(year,
                    month,
                    day)]
```

Now you cannot change the number of rows in the data.table without rewriting like `dt<-unique(dt)` according to discussion in this feature request: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635.

Comment: thanks for the issue link. I seem to be a few years behind on `data.table`. The duplicate rows seem to be a result of grouping and modifying the `val` column by reference using `:=`. Is there a way to include that operation, using `lapply` into a `data.table` chain? I can create the new `data.table`, but the flow would be better if I could chain it and the rows of the `data.table` are modified according to the grouping `by` variables.

Comment: They aren't duplicated. They are the same rows from your initial data.table. You can remove it by using dt<-unique(dt), not with ":=" interface.

Comment: You are right, they are not duplicated. `lapply` creates the new column `val` with the same value for all rows in the grouping variables. I will continue reading and just assign to a new variable for now...

Comment: I see now that what I was after is not possible. I recreated the example on the Reference semantics documentation and got the same result as what I was experiencing in my own analysis. That, in addition with the link that @Vladimir Volokhonsky provided confirmed it.